# How are variables being passed between recursive scopes in python?

Tags: python, scope

I wrote a recursive function to calculate the fibonacci sequence for a given number. I implemented a dictionary to remember past calculations for efficiency:

```
def fib_dict2(n,d):
    if n in d.keys():
        return d[n]
    else:
        var = fib_dict2(n-1,d) + fib_dict2(n-2,d)
        d[n]=var
        return var
d = {0:1,1:1}
print(fib_dict2(5,d))
print(d)
```

Results in:

```
8
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 8}
```

I see that changing the dictionary, `d`, in one scope changes d in all other scopes. I was led to believe that variables were unique to the scope in which they are generated.

Is this not the case? How does variable sharing through scopes work?

Comment: The *variable* isn't being shared. But the *different variables* are all referring to the same object. This is * no different* that `x = []` then `y = x` and `x.append(42); print(y)`

Answer (score 1):

Each *variable* `d` is unique to its own scope.  If you were to do:

```
def fib_dict2(n,d):
    d = {}  # fresh new dict
    ...
```

You would find that this change to `d` inside the scope of the function does not affect the global `d` outside of the function, or any of the other `d`s inside the other function calls.

However, *objects* in Python do not have scope -- objects continue to exist as long as *any* variable in *any* scope refers to them.  If a bunch of different variables (like all those `d`s, all in their own scopes) all point to the same object, then that object can be changed by code that is executing in any scope.

Since your actual code doesn't assign `d` to any other value (like my example above does), and every recursive call passes `d` as an argument without changing what it refers to, all of those variables in all of those scopes refer to the same dictionary that was provided as the `d` argument in the original top-level function call.

Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html